# How to trigger drag event manually while mouse still is down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I create a new draggable element after the mouse is in a down position and before it is released.
I want to trigger drag event on the new element, so it will follow my mouse moving.
It works fine in safari and chrome, but not in **Firefox**, what can I do with it?

```js
  function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
  }
  const insertBeforeSibling = ({
    target, origin
  }) => {
    origin.parentNode.insertBefore(target, origin);
  };
  const p = document.querySelector('#p');
  p.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
    const S = document.createElement('div');
    S.innerHTML = 'I am draggable';
    S.setAttribute('id', 'drag');
    S.setAttribute('draggable', true);
    S.setAttribute('ondragstart', 'drag(event)')
    insertBeforeSibling({
      target: S,
      origin: p
    });
  })
```

```css
#drag {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
#p {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
#p > div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="p">
  <div>When mousedown,a draggable green box will cover me.</div>
  <div>I hope the green box will keep dragging if you dont loose your mouse and keep going</div>
  <div>It works fine in chrome and safari,but not firefox</div>
</div>
```